# thread executing before

Tags: android, android-widget, android-2.2-froyo

i have a little bit of a problem here when calling a new thread.

I am making a audio recording app and i call the recording/playback in separate threads.

There is a button to start the recording. I am trying to update the button with new text via a handler.post object and method.

The problem is it takes too long to update. The text doesnt update till after the thread(s) run +5 secs longer.

can someone help me? please?

```
  package com.EJH.Industries.microkr;

import android.media.AudioFormat;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.AudioRecord;
import android.media.AudioTrack;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.media.MediaSyncEvent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
//CLASS VARIABLES
    //CHAR SEQUENCE
    CharSequence easyChar = "PLAYING";
    public Handler textViewHandler = new Handler();

    //CREATE THE RECORDING OBJECT
    int audioSrc = MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC;
    int sampleRate = 44100;
    int chanConfig = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO;
    int audioFormat = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;
    int getMinBuffSize = 200*AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(sampleRate, chanConfig, audioFormat);
    int minBuffSize = (int) getMinBuffSize;
    short audioBuff[] = new short[minBuffSize];
    public AudioRecord micRecorder = new AudioRecord(audioSrc, 22050, chanConfig, audioFormat, minBuffSize);



    //CREATE THE PLAYBACK OBJECT
    int streamType = AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC;
    int playMode = AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM;
    int playChanConfig = AudioFormat. CHANNEL_OUT_MONO;
    public AudioTrack speakerPlay = new AudioTrack(streamType, sampleRate, playChanConfig, audioFormat, 8192, playMode);



    public void startRec(){
        micRecorder.startRecording();
        micRecorder.read(audioBuff, 0, minBuffSize);
        micRecorder.stop();
        micRecorder.release();
    }

    public void startPlayback(){

        speakerPlay.play();
        speakerPlay.write(audioBuff, 0, minBuffSize);
        speakerPlay.stop();

    }









    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final Button startBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startButton);
        startBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                Thread recThread = new Thread( new Runnable(){

                    public void run() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                        textViewHandler.post(new Runnable () {
                            public void run(){
                                startBtn.setText("Recording!");
                            }

                        });


                        startRec();
                    }

                });

                // RUN RECORDING FUNCTION
                recThread.run();
                try {
                    recThread.join();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


                Thread playThread = new Thread( new Runnable(){

                    public void run() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        startPlayback();
                    }

                });





                playThread.run();
                try {
                    playThread.join();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }

        });

    ///////END onCreate//////////    
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think so it is because you are calling startRec() first and then running the recThread..try to modify your code as below..that is remove your startRec() function from above recThread.run() line and add it after try catch..hope it helped you..

```
Thread recThread = new Thread( new Runnable(){

                    public void run() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                        textViewHandler.post(new Runnable () {
                            public void run(){
                                startBtn.setText("Recording!");
                            }

                        });

                  //remove it from here..
                       // startRec();
                    }

                });

     // RUN RECORDING FUNCTION
                recThread.run();
                try {
                    recThread.join();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
    //add here..
                startRec();
```

Comment: thankyou for your response. I want startRec() to be on a separate thread. doessnt moving it put it on the UI thread instead of its own?

Comment: i moved some functions around and got it working, i think it was the thread. Thanks!